AWS Route53 zone export leaves ambiguous weight policy
I'm probably overlooking something. I'm programmatically exporting Route53 zone records using the Powershell SDK. The ResourceRecordSet that is returned for each entry in the zone has a weight property which is an Int64 data type. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Route53/TResourceRecordSet.html
However, when a DNS entry is not using the Weighted Routing policy, then weight is actually supposed to be null. Because the data type is an Int64 this seems to translate to 0. The problem is 0 is a valid value, and if it is specified when creating the record programmatically then the routing policy changes to Weighted Routing. That can be shown in the Edit-R53ResourceRecordSet documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Edit-R53ResourceRecordSet.html
It appears the only thing that decides if the record is created with a simple routing policy or a weighted routing policy is the null/non-null value of weight.
Therefore, it is now ambiguous if the exported record is supposed to have a Weighted Routing policy with 0 weight - which is valid, or if it is supposed to be a Simple Routing policy.
PS> (Get-R53ResourceRecordSet -HostedZoneId $zone.Id -MaxItem 1000).ResourceRecordSets
Name                    : simple.my-domain.com.
Type                    : A
SetIdentifier           : 
Weight                  : 0
Region                  : 
GeoLocation             : 
Failover                : 
MultiValueAnswer        : False
TTL                     : 300
ResourceRecords         : {Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecord}
AliasTarget             : 
HealthCheckId           : 
TrafficPolicyInstanceId : 
CidrRoutingConfig       : 
GeoProximityLocation    : 

Name                    : weighted.my-domain.com.
Type                    : A
SetIdentifier           : 
Weight                  : 0
Region                  : 
GeoLocation             : 
Failover                : 
MultiValueAnswer        : False
TTL                     : 300
ResourceRecords         : {Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecord}
AliasTarget             : 
HealthCheckId           : 
TrafficPolicyInstanceId : 
CidrRoutingConfig       : 
GeoProximityLocation    : 

PS> (Get-R53ResourceRecordSet -HostedZoneId $zone.Id -MaxItem 1000).ResourceRecordSets[0] | Get-Member

   TypeName: Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecordSet

Name                    MemberType Definition
----                    ---------- ----------
Equals                  Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode             Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType                 Method     type GetType()
ToString                Method     string ToString()
AliasTarget             Property   Amazon.Route53.Model.AliasTarget AliasTarget {get;set;}
CidrRoutingConfig       Property   Amazon.Route53.Model.CidrRoutingConfig CidrRoutingConfig {get;set;}
Failover                Property   Amazon.Route53.ResourceRecordSetFailover Failover {get;set;}
GeoLocation             Property   Amazon.Route53.Model.GeoLocation GeoLocation {get;set;}
GeoProximityLocation    Property   Amazon.Route53.Model.GeoProximityLocation GeoProximityLocation {get;set;}
HealthCheckId           Property   string HealthCheckId {get;set;}
MultiValueAnswer        Property   bool MultiValueAnswer {get;set;}
Name                    Property   string Name {get;set;}
Region                  Property   Amazon.Route53.ResourceRecordSetRegion Region {get;set;}
ResourceRecords         Property   System.Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecord] ResourceRecords {get;set;}
SetIdentifier           Property   string SetIdentifier {get;set;}
TrafficPolicyInstanceId Property   string TrafficPolicyInstanceId {get;set;}
TTL                     Property   long TTL {get;set;}
Type                    Property   Amazon.Route53.RRType Type {get;set;}
Weight                  Property   long Weight {get;set;}

The problem is essentially the same for the ttl value when using an alias type record.

Where does it say "weight is actually supposed to be null"?

@jdweng The documentation doesn't say that. But it can be deduced by a few things. 1) exporting the zone via aws cli to json works properly (the weight property does not exist in the output when weight routing policy is not enabled). 2) It is impossible to determine if an exported zone via API SDK is supposed to have a weighted routing policy applied, because the weight property is the only property that determines that. 3) Powershell is known to convert a null Int64 to 0. 4) Trying to import a record with weight property = 0 enables weighted routing policy. The problem is defined.

@jdweng https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html - Output / Weight (Long) - "Weighted resource record sets only"

Do you have a weight for every item?  Documentation says "You must specify a value for the Weight element for every weighted resource record set."

@jdweng you're missing the point. Not every record is a weighted resource record type. That is the point. A weighted resource record type is exported exactly the same as a simple routing record type. The only differentiator between these two is the weight property, which is present on both objects, using the SDK, even though it should not be. Behind the scenes, the API does not include the weight property on non weighted records. Because the weight property is typed to Int64 it's being converted to 0 instead of null. 0 is a valid weight. AWS CLI does not do that.

@jdweng that is my best explanation of the problem. Doesn't mean I'm right, but I've spent enough time on it now to know I shouldn't be seeing any value for weight or at least I should see a value outside of [0...255] when the record is not a weighted record. The converse function Edit-R53ResourceRecordSet accepts, but does not require, the weight property. If it is specified, it will create a weighted record type. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Edit-R53ResourceRecordSet.html

I'm just stating what the documentation says and do not know the source code to figure out what happens when there NO WEIGHT.  I would ask this question to the people who support the library.
